# What is better performance for dedupe in spark reduceByKey or join

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm creating some batch user repository, where I need to store the deduped users. Having that, lets assumpt that there is some repository (n) with already deduped users, and I want to create a repository (n+1) that will take repo[n-1]+rawdata[n], and create repo[n]

What will be the better performance/implementation for that ?

```
case class UserProfileRow(userId: String, ts: Long, upData: String)
```

solution1:

```
val raw_n = sc.textFile(rawInput).map(parseRow(_)).map(r=>(r.userId,r))
val repo_n_1 = sc.textFile(repoInput).map(parseRow(_)).map(r=>(r.userId,r))
raw_n.union(repo_n_1)
     .reduceByKey(_ maxTs _, numberPartitions)
     .saveAsTextFile(repoOutput)
```

solution2:

```
val raw_n = sc.textFile(rawInput).map(parseRow(_)).map(r=>(r.userId,r))
            .reduceByKey(_ maxTs _, numberPartitions)
val repo_n_1 = sc.textFile(repoInput).map(parseRow(_)).map(r=>(r.userId,r))

repo_n_1.fullOuterJoin(raw_n).mapValues{
  case (Some(uRepo), None)=> uRepo
  case (_, Some(uRaw))=> uRaw
}.saveAsTextFile(repoOutput)
```

Is there any better approach to perform such operation.
The problem is that rawdata could be large  - bigger than couple gigas, so I would avoid to put it as broadcast to context.